# using JSONP fetch cross domain JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to use JSONP to fetch JSON data via cross domain.
And I know that JSONP format is different to JSON format.
So the cross domain server returns JSON format to me, is there any method that I can change it to JSONP format?
Thanks.

PS: I am trying to get data from other servers.
my code:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
ajaxCallJsonp("http://bafs.com.hk/system/template/ajax/json_test.php?callback=?");

function ajaxCallJsonp(target){

    var data = $.getJSON(target,
    {
        value: "mount rainier",
        name: "123",
        pk: "1"
    });

    data.success(function( msg ) {
        $("#result").html(msg.b);
    });

    data.error(function( msg ) {
        $("#result").html("fail getting data"+msg.readyState);
    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: i believe they the same JSONP just has a callback but format wise just the same.. for cross domain i think you need JSONP

Comment: You want to `fetch` data or to `send` data? There is a big difference between the two. Also, what have you tried? Please show us your code.

Comment: lonut : I am trying to fetch data :D

Comment: Your code seems to work. So you want `JSONP` instead of `JSON`? Why do you want to do that when you already fetch data in `JSON` format? Anyway, you can just set the `dataType` to `jsonp` in your `AJAX` call.

Comment: Actually I don't mind JSONP or JSON, but the fact is the server is returning JSON format to me. And $.getJSON method expects JSONP format.